# Ionic React JSX element type 'false | Element' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Type 'false

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the following components Timeline and TimeLineItem:

```
import React from 'react';
import TimelineItem from './TimelineItem';


const timelineData = [
    {
        text: 'Started working on the app-ideas repository',
        date: 'May 25 2020',
        category: {
            tag: 'app-ideas',
            color: '#FFDB14'
        },
        link: {
            url: 'https://google.com',
            text: 'Check it out on GitHub'
        }
    },
    ................
]
const Timeline = () =>
    timelineData.length > 0 && (
        <div className="timeline-container">
            {timelineData.map((data: any, idx: any) => (
                <TimelineItem data={data} key={idx} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );

export default Timeline;
```

```
import React from 'react';

interface AppliedRouteProps {
    data: any;
}
const TimelineItem = ({ data }: AppliedRouteProps) => (
    <div className="timeline-item">
        <div className="timeline-item-content">
            <span className="tag" style={{ background: data.category.color }}>
                {data.category.tag}
            </span>
            <time>{data.date}</time>
            <p>{data.text}</p>
            {data.link && (
                <a
                    href={data.link.url}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    {data.link.text}
                </a>
            )}
            <span className="circle" />
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default TimelineItem;
```

The page:

```
const TimeLineAuto = () => <>
    <h1>React Timeline</h1>
    <Timeline />
</>;
```

I'm receiving errors on the Timeline call tag in TimeLineAuto: SX element type 'false | Element' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2605)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
const Timeline = () =>
    timelineData.length > 0 ? (
    <div className="timeline-container">
      {timelineData.map((data: any, idx: any) => (
        <TimelineItem data={data} key={idx} />
      ))}
    </div>
  ) : null;
```

with your old code, when `timelineData.length > 0` was false, it would return `false` which is not an acceptable return value. The new code will return `null` which is